# Arch - KDE Plasma 5.7 and Latte Dock: Icons do not appear

Tags: kde, icons, kde5, dock

I've recently installed Arch and chose KDE5 for my desktop environment. Being a fan of docks, I've opted to install Latte.

The problem is that icons do not appear in my dock at all, thus rendering it pretty much unusable.

[image: no Latte icons]

I remember reading somewhere in a bug report (which I can't find at the moment, and was really difficult to find in the first place) that Latte uses libtaskmanager to display the icons. However, the task manager has no issues displaying icons whatsoever. How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe you need to add the icons ....  try drag and drop

Comment: Nope, not at all.

Comment: Just curious. You're on Arch so why have you gone with Plasma 5.7 instead of Plasma 5.14?

Comment: That's just what pacman happened to install.

Comment: Hmm... What is your version of Latte Dock? Some sites claim it works better with Plasma 5.9 and above. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/latte-dock-0-8-released-with-widget-separators-setup-sharing-more as an example.

Comment: Dude, that's exactly what the problem was! I didn't install the `plasma-meta` package! If you add your answer, I'll accept it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please go ahead and post an answer yourself. I have no direct experience with Arch!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had installed the wrong KDE package because I installed the `plasma-desktop` package, which gave me KDE 5.7. I needed to install the `plasma-meta` package as follows to get KDE 5.14:

`sudo pacman -S plasma-meta`

After that, Latte works as it should!

Comment: Do *not* `pacman -Sy $package`: it will lead to [breakage](https://gist.github.com/vodik/5660494)...

Comment: That would certainly explain why I'm experiencing my [current issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481115/alsa-sound-stopped-working-in-arch-for-usb-sound-card-after-upgrading-kde-from) lol. I'll edit.