# ALSA - Sound stopped working in Arch for USB sound card after upgrading KDE from 5.7 to 5.14

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, usb-audio

Yesterday, I upgraded KDE from 5.7 to 5.14 after having display issues because it turns out I had installed the wrong package. I had some trouble initially getting sound to work in 5.7, but I finally managed to get it to detect and use my USB sound card (Bose USB Speakers).

However, after upgrading, it must have also done something with ALSA, as it's stopped playing sound altogether and can only detect on-board cards.

I know the system is detecting the device on the lowest layer because here is the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 007: ID 1410:1410 Novatel Wireless Merlin U740 (non-Vodafone)
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 007 Device 006: ID 04d9:4545 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc. G502 Mouse
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 05a7:1020 Bose Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0d8c:016c C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 048d:8295 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Sure enough, there's the Bose speakers in Device 002 on Bus 007.

But here's my output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So as you can see, no USB sound cards whatsoever have been found. I tried loading the `snd-usb-audio` module with `modprobe snd-usb-audio` and verified the module was loaded with `cat /proc/modules | grep snd`:

```
snd_seq_dummy 16384 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_seq_oss 45056 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_seq_midi_event 16384 1 snd_seq_oss, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_seq 81920 5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi_event, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_pcm_oss 61440 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_mixer_oss 28672 1 snd_pcm_oss, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_codec_hdmi 57344 1 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_codec_realtek 110592 1 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_usb_audio 249856 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_codec_generic 86016 1 snd_hda_codec_realtek, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_intel 45056 5 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_usbmidi_lib 32768 1 snd_usb_audio, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_codec 151552 4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_rawmidi 36864 1 snd_usbmidi_lib, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_seq_device 16384 3 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hda_core 94208 5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hwdep 16384 2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_pcm 131072 6 snd_pcm_oss,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_timer 36864 2 snd_seq,snd_pcm, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd 98304 26 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer, Live 0x0000000000000000
soundcore 16384 1 snd, Live 0x0000000000000000
```

As we can see, snd_usb_audio is loaded.

So why isn't my sound card being detected? I tried `alsactl init`, `alsactl nrestore`, and `alsactl kill rescan`. None of those had any effect. Additionally, `alsamixer` does not display the device either.

So this is more like several questions now, I suppose: how do I get it working initially, and then how do I get it to work on system start afterward? And how did this happen in the first place? I don't think upgrading a desktop environment under any circumstance should affect my system's ability to find a sound card.

Comment: What's `usbstream:CARD=Generic`? And why is the list from `aplay -l` not complete?

Comment: That's either the webcam or the Yeti microphone (since it has sound out). As for why the list is incomplete, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I more meant, you've copy pasted a incomplete list. There should be at least a header to the first item. Like `jack` is a header to all the below parameters.

Comment: Edited with full output, though there are less devices this time.